# is Dynamic form rendering in iOS app allowed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, titanium-mobile

In an app I need to download an xml(metadata for form to be rendered) from remote and then render a form accordingly. I wonder if this is allowed under apple guidelines as so far I did not encounter any such thing in HIG guidelines.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I would have thought so, as long as you stick to the guidelines WRT size, spacing, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

I think its allowed (I don't see any reason to reject such apps). In few of my apps I am rendering forms based on some conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed as long as the content you render dynamically, is okay as far as the guidelines are concerned. You may compare this to having a UIWebView load dynamic content off of the web.